# Regex can not find all the required expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

i`m learning python and also english. I'm probably taking a very amateur approach to my problem.
I'm trying to find a sequence of 17 numbers in .txt files. I have thousands of files and I've been creating regular expressions for the most common types of occurrences I've noticed, for example:

> 01582.2005.012.02.00-\r\n 3\r\n
>
> nº 01387.2009.466.02.00­1\r\n
>
> nº 01462. 2008. 030. 02. 00­0\r\n
>
> nº0033620084610200-­0\r\n
>
> n. 02414.2008.023.02.00­1 (201...
>
> nº 00030.2007.084.02.00-3 (2
>
> nº 00627.2009.006.02.00­4\r\n
>
> nº 0001491-6020125020
>
> numero: 00028.2009.031.02.00-0\r\n
>
> n 00012.2010.391.02.00-0 - 7ª tu
>
> nº 0000695720135020402
>
> nº 00037.2007.048.02.00-1\r\n
>
> 01113.2009.074.02.00.4.\r
>
> proc: - 00396-25.2011.5.02-0020
>
> n.º 0163100-53-2010.5.02.0341
>
> nº 01230.2007.065.02.0.0-5 - 7ª tu
>
> nº 64587.2009.\r\n 549.02.00­1\r\n

The regular expressions that I created were able to find the sequences in about 70% of the files, but I got to a point that for each new regex I do, the number of sequences found is so insignificant in relation to what is missing, that I feel counting sand in the desert. Some of the regex I used were these:

```
search = re.search(r'((\d{5})\.?\s*(\d{4})\.?\s*(\d{3})\.?\s*(\d{2})\.?\s*(\d{2})\-?\s*(\d))', content.read())
search = re.search(r'((\d{5})\.(\d{4})\.(\d{3})\.(\d{2})\.(\d)\-(\d{2}))', content.read())
search = re.search(r'((\d{5})\.(\d{4})\.(\d{3})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d))', content.read())
```

they could find some of these examples I gave, but most of them did not. what I would like to know is how can I take a broader approach to my regex than I am doing. thankss.

edit: What I have more problems to find, are those that have line breaks or spaces between the "-" or "\"

Comment: You can probably just get rid of all those characters coming in between your numbers. That is `content.read().replace('.', '').replace('-','')` and you would have better time writing the regex.

Comment: But how do I use the replace before finding them in the text? Or would I use it in the whole text?

Comment: I'm not too sure what exactly you would like as result. But if you check the following regex against your numbers on regex101.com I get a match for almost all number combinations: \d{2,}(\d|\.|\-|\s|\­)+ . Also my regex assumes that all your number patterns begin with at least 2 digits

Comment: The ones separated by linebreaks I could not match against.

Answer (score 0):

Not being sure if there's some underlying pattern to all those sequences I'm not seeing, I tested this maybe-too-generic one in regex101 with your input and got one full-match per each of those lines, matching the first sequence of 17 in each of them (where the numbers can have some special characters like punctuation between them).

```
(\d([\s,.\-\xAD_]|(\\r)|(\\n))*){17}
```

(or: `(?:\d(?:[\s,.\-\xAD_]|(?:\\r)|(?:\\n))*){17}` if you want to avoid capturing those groups. You can also surround the whole thing between parenthesis to capture the full match if you want)

Also included "\r" and "\n" literally written out (`\s` takes care of spaces and actual line breaks, if there were any, between numbers), since you've written them out explicitly in that input so I had to do that to consider them part of the sequence.

Basically it says: *Match, 17 times in a row: A digit, followed by any amount of any of these characters or literally '\r' or '\n'*. And you can add anything you'd like to consider as part of the number sequence (like, maybe slashes should also be ignored) to this part of the regex `([\s,.\-\xAD_]|(\\r)|(\\n))`. Anything that isn't in that part of the regex is gonna break or separate potential sequences (so letters or punctuation I might've missed)

But not being super regex knowledgeable, I'm not all that happy with that and I really think Jay's suggestion is the best place to start: Figure out what characters are only an annoyance to you, remove those from the whole text, and hopefully looking for the sequences is easier after that.

Btw, here:

```
0163100-53-2010.5.02.0341
```

There are 20 numbers, so the 341 is not part of the full match since it comes after the first 17 (same with some other lines with more that 17 numbers in a row), and I'm not sure if that's what you want.